# Initialize ApplicationContext in base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have started learning project in .net core. It is SPA application.
I have created base repository in which i want to inintialize ApplicationDbContext which derives by ApiAuthorizationDbContext.

Database context intitialization somehow works by dependency injection but will not work for base repository class where injected objects are by constructor. I had to inject context for every repository which in my point of view is useless. I'd prefer to instantiate such context manually.

My problem is that ApiAuthorizationDbContext require operationalStoreOptions. I can not find how to configure these options. In below code fragment there is constructor which i have to use.

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(
            DbContextOptions options,
            IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to be instantiate it manually, Then inject the operational store instead

Comment: If you don't want to inject that then create the operation store manually, but really you should just use the Dependency Injector to do everything, the purpose of the architecture is to make your life easier, so why do you want a hard dependency on ApiAuthorizationDbContext

Comment: also if your issue is the code in your  repository class you should probably post that.

Comment: Maybe that is not true that i do not want to inject context via depencency injection, but am I right that if would i should do it in every repository? In my opinion one central class is good place for context

Comment: What? You don't have to inject it in every class, but if you need it you either need to inject in where you need it, Or Inject something that contains it where you need it.  You lose the majority of the benefits of Dependency Injection if you don't fully use it.  One of the main benefits of DI is so you have granular control of your application.  Manually instantiating dependencies will not only mess up testing but also make it harder for you to change dependencies in the future

Comment: Ok, if i inject this context to repositories in which i need it it will be ok, but  what with the base class which i use now? I have in it some generic methods like save etc ...
I think that i could pass context to property of base class and operate on it. Thank you

Comment: If you don't need a specific context for your repository pattern, then take a generic DBContext in the constructor, when you repostiory pattern requires it, you can inherit from the base, but require the `AuthorizedContext` in the Repository, that way your base class is no dependent on functionality that is only required in the main repo, alternatively you create 2 base classes, but its better to consolidate into one and seperate concerns when you can

Comment: I also need to know this for different reasons. We're sharing a context between an online app and a local console app, and in the console app DI is not configured by default in dotnet core.